# Why i can't get the response header from cross domain jQuery.ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, cross-domain

the code：

```
//use jQuery.ajax
               $.ajax({
                    url: 'http://localhost:9733/Home/AjaxIndex',
                    type: 'get',
                    dataType: 'jsonp',
                    jsonpCallback: 'callback',
                    complete: function (jqXHR) {
                        console.log(jqXHR.getAllResponseHeaders())
                        console.log('=================================')
                    }
                })
                .always(function (d, s, jqXHR) {
                    console.log(jqXHR.getAllResponseHeaders())
                    console.log('=================================')
                })
//use XMLHttpRequest
                var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest()
                xhr.open('get', 'http://localhost:9733/Home/AjaxIndex')
                xhr.onload = function () {
                    console.log('load:', xhr.getAllResponseHeaders())
                    console.log('=================================')
                }
                xhr.send()
```

and the result:

```
=================================

=================================
load: Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PUT, DELETE
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Cache-Control: private
```

So i can't get the response headers from the jQuery.ajax,but can get it from XMLHttpRequest?

If i want to get it, i can only use the XMLHttpRequest?

Comment: `jsonp` is a script request , not an XmlHttpRequest. Not sure why you are requesting jsonp if it isn't needed

Comment: @charlietfl Oh,i get it. So if i use jQuery.ajax to cross domain, the jqXHR.getALLResponseHeaders is useless

Comment: No...`$.ajax` will use `XmlHttpRequest` for any request that isn't jsonp. Sounds like you don't need jsonp and should make a regular request with `$.ajax`

Comment: @charlietfl Yeah, i get it.thx so much!